# Unable to save/write tree data that plotBS() results

Tags: r, phylogeny, ggtree

I have aligned sequences in class of `phyDat`. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(seqinr)
seqs <- DNAMultipleAlignment( c(a1 = "------ATGTTCATTAACCGCTGACTATTCTCAACCA",
                                a2 = "------ATGTTCACCGACCGCTGACTATTCTCTACAA",
                                a3 = "---GTGACCTTCATCAACCGATGATTATTCTCAA---",
                                a4 = "---TCAGTCGTCACCAGGCGTTG-CAGGACCCGAC--",
                                a5 = "ATGGGGGTCTTCCTCA-TCGCCGTCGCCGCGT-----"))

library(phangorn)
phyDat_seqs <- as.phyDat(seqs)
```

I followed the [manual of phangorn package](http://r.adu.org.za/web/packages/phangorn/vignettes/Trees.pdf) to construct a phylogenic tree. (Below, I wrote a simplified code. You don't need to check manual, you can run the code directly.)

```
dm <- dist.ml(phyDat_seqs)
treeNJ <- NJ(dm)

fit <- pml(treeNJ, data=phyDat_seqs)
fitGTR <- optim.pml(fit, model="GTR")

bs <- bootstrap.pml(fitGTR, bs=5, optNni=TRUE)
```

And I can simply plot this tree with `plotBS` :

```
plotBS(fitGTR$tree, bs, type="p")
```

**There is no problem so far. My question starts from this point**.

I want to customize this tree by using `ggtree` package but I couldn't figure out how to do that. When I use `ggtree(fitGTR$tree)`, it gives me a different tree.

`plotBS` somehow uses `bs` values to change tree branching. If you compare `plot(fitGTR$tree, type="p")` and `plotBS(fitGTR$tree, bs, type="p")` difference can easily be seen. `ggtree()` and  `plot()` construct the same trees, but not the tree that I want to customize.

I've tried different approaches such as saving tree with `write.tree` or `write.nexus` functions and calling the file again with `ggtree` package functions but I can't save the `plotBS` version of the tree. How can I get an output of `plotBS` tree?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was occuring because I misread the documentation. I did a mistake in this line:

```
plotBS(fitGTR$tree, bs, type="p")
```

Tree must be constructed through `midpoint()` function. Therefore, when I changed the line as this:

```
plotBS(midpoint(fitGTR$tree), bs, type="p")
```

no problem occurs. I can use `ggtree` and I can save/write the tree data without a problem.

Even if I can't figure out what `midpoint()` function does to tree actually (you can comment about this), problem is solved.